# How to cancel Gesture if it goes beyond container's bound in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, gesture

I'm implementing a Drawing App in Flutter. I'm referring [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7ZmQEXqmGA)  but Somehow I got stuck by an

[image: issue]

Brief: As you can see I have two container. One for Drawing and below one for 'Draw Above'. But points drawn its beyond.I want user can draw within the upper container. So my question is -
How to cancel Gesture detection, if it goes beyond a particular container's bounds?

Code snippet:

```
final GestureDetector paintGesture = GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
      Offset _localPosition = object.localToGlobal(details.globalPosition);
      _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
    });
  },
  onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      _points.add(null);
  },
  child: sketchArea,
);

final Container sketchArea = Container(
  //margin: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
  //alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  color: Colors.white,
  child: new CustomPaint(
    painter: new Signature(points: _points),
    size: Size.infinite,
  ),
);
```

Scaffold:

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child:  paintGesture,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                _selectedInput,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 40.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: @TruongSinh, I've already posted my main code snippet. As SO recommended not to confuse users by posting long post, make it clear and understandable. I know I've to add some check on these below but don't know how to apply in dart -
`RenderBox object = context.findRenderObject();
      Offset _localPosition = object.localToGlobal(details.globalPosition);
      _points = new List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);`

Comment: @TruongSinh I've updated my post. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution by vovohost from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58788092/3545278) to get the coordinates of my `Container` :

**Extension :**

```
extension GlobalKeyExtension on GlobalKey {
  Rect get globalPaintBounds {
    final renderObject = currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    var translation = renderObject?.getTransformTo(null)?.getTranslation();
    if (translation != null && renderObject.paintBounds != null) {
      return renderObject.paintBounds
          .shift(Offset(translation.x, translation.y));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
final containerKey = GlobalKey();
Rect get containerRect => containerKey.globalPaintBounds;

Container(
  key: containerKey,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
)

void printWidgetPosition() {
  print('absolute coordinates on screen: ${containerRect}');
}
```

Once I got the coordinates, I had to use this method to return an `Offset` within bounds of my `Container` :

```
Offset _offsetInBox(Offset globalOffset) {
  // Y coordinate
  double nearestY = 0;
  if (globalOffset.dy >= containerRect.top &&
      globalOffset.dy <= containerRect.bottom) {
    nearestY = globalOffset.dy;
  } else {
    if ((containerRect.top - globalOffset.dy).abs() >
        (containerRect.bottom - globalOffset.dy).abs()) {
      nearestY = containerRect.bottom;
    } else {
      nearestY = containerRect.top;
    }
  }

  // X coordinate
  double nearestX = 0;
  if (globalOffset.dx >= containerRect.left &&
      globalOffset.dx <= containerRect.right) {
    nearestX = globalOffset.dx;
  } else {
    if ((containerRect.left - globalOffset.dx).abs() >
        (containerRect.right - globalOffset.dx).abs()) {
      nearestX = containerRect.right;
    } else {
      nearestX = containerRect.left;
    }
  }
  print(
      "Global[${globalOffset.dx}, ${globalOffset.dy}], Found=[$nearestX, $nearestY]");

  return Offset(nearestX, nearestY);
}
```

On your GestureDetector, use it like this :

```
final GestureDetector paintGesture = GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
      // Use the globalToLocal method if you want the local coordinates, not localToGlobal
      Offset _localPosition = renderBox
                      .globalToLocal(_offsetInBox(details.globalPosition));
      _points = List.from(_points)..add(_localPosition);
    });
  },
  onPanEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
      _points.add(null);
  },
  child: sketchArea,
);

final Container sketchArea = Container(
  key: containerKey,
  color: Colors.white,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: Signature(points: _points),
    size: Size.infinite,
  ),
);
```