# Get index of the widget at the top visible of a list view builder

Tags: flutter

I would like to know the index of the top visible widget in my `ListViewBuilder`

======================================

At this point I should get `index 12`

[image]

At this point I should get `index 21`

[image]

```
class XXX extends StatelessWidget {
  const XXX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test')),
      body: ListView.builder(
          reverse: true,
          itemCount: 50,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              color: index.isEven ? Colors.amber : Colors.yellow,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              child: Text("HELLO $index"),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to know if a widget is visible within a viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069712/how-to-know-if-a-widget-is-visible-within-a-viewport)

Comment: Is it same case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615525/11986450